# How to use a Method of an Active Form

Tags: c#, methods

I got a DesktopAlert(AddinModule.cs) with buttons and when I click on one of them,
I want a grid to get filled with Data in a Form which is already open (WEV_TechControl.Taskpanes.paneAufgaben)

What I have tried:

In  WEV_TechControl.Taskpanes.paneAufgaben:

```
public void ExecuteWarn()
        {
            try
            {...}
            catch {...}
        }
```

this is the method I want to call.

And

```
    public class AddinModule : AddinExpress.MSO.ADXAddinModule
    {
void Info_Warn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       Myaddin.Taskpanes.paneAufgaben Pane = (WEV_TechControl.Taskpanes.paneAufgaben)Myaddin.Taskpanes.paneAufgaben.ActiveForm;
       Pane.ExecuteWarn();
        }
       }
```

But I get a NullReference Error.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is cannot reach another form/class instance for your current form/class. There is lot of solution given for these problem as "How to use another form instance/controls".